# Spring Task Executor not firing until previous task is complete

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, task, spring-annotations

I have a method in a class that has the @Scheduled annotation

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
public void doSomething() {

}
```

This should execute every second (assuming the cron statement is correct).

I have the sping config setup as

```
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="2" />
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="2" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" scheduler="taskScheduler" />
```

The problem is that the method will not fire again until the last execution is complete. I was expecting to see it fire twice (and possibly start filling up a job queue somewhere).

How can i remove the dependancy between method calls, but still ensure only have 2 processes runninig at one time.

Comment: This is explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197904/why-does-spring-task-scheduler-wait-for-previous-task-to-finish

Answer (score 0):

It seems an idea would be to past the actual work to the taskExecutor

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
 public void doSomething() {
   this.executor.execute(new Runnable() {...}
 }
```

then add a rejection policy as *CALLER_RUNS*

```
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="1" />
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="1"
    queue-capacity="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor"
    scheduler="taskScheduler" />
```

So with above, the work is always done by one thread pool.

not sure if this is the best way thou.

Answer (score 0):

No new execution is triggered since the scheduler-thread is busy running your task.

In order to achieve the behaviour you are asking for is to delegate the task to the executor-thread. The easiest way to do that is to simply annotate the method with @Async.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
@Async
public void doSomething() {
   ...
}
```

Keep in mind though, that you would have to trim the task-executor pool size to a desired capacity in order to accomodate for enough executor-threads running in parallell.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [`@Scheduled`](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) with `fixedRate`-value instead of `cron` or `fixedDelay`:

> **fixedRate**
> Execute the annotated method with a fixed period between invocations.
>
> **fixedDelay**
> Execute the annotated method with a fixed period between the end of the last invocation and the start of the next.

With **fixedRate**, another execution of the method is scheduled to happen a certain amount of time after the last time the task *started*.

With **fixedDelay** the next invocation occurs a certain amount of time after the last time the task *ended*.

Naturally your thread pool must have another free thread for the task to run on time (if the previous one is still executing).

Comment: Does not work : using fixed rate, it does not trigger the same method again. Also with fixed rate/fixed delay you lose the flexibility of fine tuning the schedule like running on week days only, between 9-5, etc